# Can this boolean if-else statement be turned into a one-line expression?

Tags: c#, optimization

Can the following code be optimized any further (i.e. can it be turned into a one-line expression), through some bit-wise operation or something else?

```
if(A_BOOL_VARIABLE)
    return (A == B);
else
    return (A != B);
```

Note: A and B are not `bool` type here.

Comment: What optimisations do you expect? Is this code too slow?

Comment: No. I just belong to those one-liners extinguishing race.

Comment: @dotNET: I didn't downvote, but your question didn't state what kind of optimization you're looking for. Without your first comment (above), it was sort of ambiguous. I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return A_BOOL_VARIABLE == (A == B);
```

Truth table:

```
A_BOOL_VARIABLE  (A == B)   Result
    T               T         T
    T               F         F
    F               T         F
    F               F         T
```

Which is the same as your original `if..else`.

Comment: Why did you remove the truth table?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: because it was wrong. Workin' on it.

Comment: @stakx: Fixed truth table.

Answer (score 2):

Not bitwise, but a simple boolean XOR:

```
return A_BOOL_VARIABLE ^ (A!=B);
```

Here I suppose that `A==B = !(A!=B)`.

Comment: Right. This one is probably as good as Jim's answer, but he was faster. Deserves +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming your `A_BOOL_VARIABLE` to `C` for the sake of brevity, the truth table is:

```
C A B   Result

0 0 0   0 \
0 0 1   1 |  == A ^ B  (C=0)
0 1 0   1 |
0 1 1   0 /

1 0 0   1 \
1 0 1   0 |  == ! (A ^ B)    (C=1)
1 1 0   0 |
1 1 1   1 /
```

So the final expression could be: `A ^ B ^ C`   where `^` is exclusive or.

Comment: Ah no no. A and B are not `bool` type.

Comment: But I didn't mention otherwise too.

Comment: Yes. Bit-wise between `A_BOOL_VARIABLE` and the return expression. Anyway, I'll update my question to reflect the fact.